# Как подкорректировать регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно, чтобы в первой подгруппе находилось выражение: **TEST-MT** (исключение) или любое другое слово до знака "**-**", а во второй всё, что после "**-**".

Тестовые данные:

```
TEST-MT
TEST-MT-BKP-20170828
TEST-MT-TEST
TEST-LIVE
TEST-LIVE-TECHPLAN
```

Выражение [`(TEST-MT)(?:-(.*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/FFH6oN/1) правильно находит первые три строки.

Если добавляем конструкцию выбора [`(?:(TEST-MT)(?:-(.*))?|([^-]+)(?:-(.*))?)`](https://regex101.com/r/FFH6oN/2), то правильно находятся последние две строки.

Как это корректно объединить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, подредактировал:
[`(\bTEST-MT\b|\w+)(?:-(.*))?`](https://regex101.com/r/FFH6oN/3)

Используем `\bTEST-MT\b` для совпадения с целым словом, `|` или `\w+` для совпадения с одной или более букв

Comment: Благодарю! Что-то я лишнего налепил и сам запутался почему оно не работает правильно)